# Does Async Task has some form of Caching System?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I was writing a code in Android(Java) to calculate maximum prime numbers it can identify in 30 Seconds of time. When the program was executed for the first time, it calculated 35k+ Prime Numbers in 30 Second. But without closing the app, when I run it the 2nd Time, the result increases to 80k+. Anyone got any clue why this happens ?
**Async Task**

```
private class CalculatePrime extends AsyncTask<Long,Long,Long>
    {
        long starTime=0,count=1;

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(Long... objects) {
            starTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            long nos=3;
            while(System.currentTimeMillis()-starTime<=objects[0])
            {
                long i;
                for(i=3;i<=nos/2;i+=2)
                {
                    if(nos%i==0)
                        break;
                }
                if(i>nos/2)
                {
                    count++;
                    publishProgress(new Long(0));
                }
                nos+=2;
            }
            return new Long(0);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values) {
            score.setText(""+count);
        }
    }
```

**Main Function call**

```
new calculatePrime().execute(new Long(30*1000));
```

**UPDATE**
So I tested this app in Android 6 Marshmallow, and to my surprise, the Code was consistent. It gave 6k+ result on subsequent runs. The issue is only relevant in Android 9. So anyone got any clue as to what might have changed between Android 6.0 and 9.0 that could result in such a behavior ?

Comment: actually when you don't close your app and back again to app, your `Async Task` was not stopped. so its continuously working. print some log to confirm this behaviour.

Comment: But the Async doBackground Task is stopping properly at 30 sec, and the 80k+ results are consistent across the 3rd,4th and 5th Run too.

Comment: The code might have been optimized since its first run.

Comment: Take a look if disabling JIT make a difference: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/jit-compiler

Answer (score 0):

put this   score.setText(""+count);  onPostExecute() method because when the doingbackground() task is complete the result go to the onPostExecute Method and you show the total counts.